# importing a virtual machine inside another virtual machine

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, virtualization, hadoop

I have a hadoop cluster of VMs hosted on VirtualBox. The VMs are all ubuntu, and the host system is windows 7.

How can I import all of these VMs into 1 ubuntu vm?

Comment: Be aware that VirtualBox does not pass VT-X/AMD-V to the guest machine - see [forum thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20589), [bug ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032). This implies that virtual machines running inside a VirtualBox VM will be painfully slow.

Comment: @ignis thank you. What about vmware? Would I be able to export the images to vmware?

Comment: VMWare Workstation 8 claims to support hardware virtualization (i.e. VT-X/AMD-V) inside the guest, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/329247/24432) for details.

Comment: is there something that is free that i can use?

Comment: Please, open a new question for that. I don't know it personally, but others may have the answer. Also see [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/328748/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization-in-ubuntu/329247#comment418775_328748) for some alternative technologies, however I don't know whether they are good replacements for a hypervisor.