# Error instaling OpenStack with juju due to kvm-ok not being installed

Tags: 14.04, juju, kvm-virtualization, openstack

I'm trying follow this [video-tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsaoU254gAc) but using VirtualBox and at the moment to install openstack (over 19:30m), I get the next error:

[image: Fatal Error]

How I can resolve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're running into this issue, KVM doesn't work inside virtualbox:

- [How to enable nested virtualization in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328748/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization-in-ubuntu)
- Bug report with Virtualbox: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032