# How to install KVM in Ubuntu virtual machine?

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I've tried to  install KVM in an Ubuntu virtual machine (versions 19.04 and then 16.04) and in both cases I get the same error:

> INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
>
> KVM acceleration can NOT be used

I can use QEMU but it's slow and I need KVM in order to install particular software. I'm using VMWare Workstation Pro.

Are there any settings I need to modify to be able to do it?

Comment: It seems that you are experiencing this issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/328748/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization-in-ubuntu.

Comment: thanks @Odecif but in that post, the user tried to install it on a Virtual Box VM, while I'm using Ubuntu

Comment: Most often you need to enable KVM somewhere in the bios. Details are unfortunately very manufacturer specific.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt but how can I do that from vmware workstation? Because my Ubuntu is a virtual machine, so I want to install a virtual machine inside a virtual machine :)

Comment: Ah that would be https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8970 then.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it by editing the setting of my Ubuntu virtual machine in VMWare Workstation: I edited the **Processor** section and enabled the option **Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI** under **Virtualization Engine**.